# Does Fermat's last theorem hold in the ordinals?

Tags: set-theory, diophantine-equations

My question is whether there are no nontrivial solutions in the ordinals of the equations arising in Fermat's last theorem $$x^n+y^n=z^n$$
where $n\gt 2$, and where we use the  [natural ordinal arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_arithmetic#Natural_operations), which is commutative.

(Note: If we had used the usual ordinal arithmetic, there are some easy counterexamples, such as $1^3+\omega^3=\omega^3$.)

The question spins off of my answer to Saint Georg's recent question, [The Theory of Transfinite Diophantine Equations](https://mathoverflow.net/a/150816/1946).

Feldmann Denis pointed out in the comments there that for very small ordinals (below $\omega^\omega$), the question reduces to the corresponding question in polynomials, where it has an affirmative answer. Can we extend this observation to work for all ordinals?

Comment: What about the analogous question for ${}^* \mathbb{N}$ or ${}^* \mathbb{Z}$ ?

Comment: @Qfwfq: prolly I am speaking junk coz. of my ignorance---if those sets are the ultrapowers, then yes this theorem does hold there (I heard Terry Tao mention that in his talk today morning) --- of course, right now I don't understand any of this, so don't take my word for it :-)

Comment: @Qfwfq, if you mean the nonstandard natural numbers and integers, then they have all the same truths as their standard counterparts, and so in particular they will satisfy FLT, as this is true in the standard realm.

Comment: This may be a naive question, but do the natural operations always respect the usual exponentiation rules? For example, do we have $\omega^{\alpha}\cdot\omega^{\beta} = \omega^{\alpha + \beta}$, where + and $\cdot$ are natural addition and multiplication?

Comment: @JDH: yes, that's what I was asking; thanks!

Comment: I observe that there are plenty of silly counterexamples for infinite exponents, like $4^{\omega+1}+5^{\omega+1}=9^{\omega+1}$, so I guess $n$ is supposed to be a natural number. Actually, what exactly do you mean by “natural ordinal arithmetic”? Does it just mean that $+$ in the equation denotes Hessenberg sum (as I have interpreted it), or is there also a “natural” exponentiation operation you want to use instead of the usual one?

Comment: Yes, I had meant that the exponent $n$ should be a natural number, and so $x^n$ means repeated multiplication. By natural ordinal arithmetic I meant what is also called Hessenberg sum and product, as in the link I had provided.

Comment: So, $x^n$ means repeated Hessenberg product?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant. But can you make a finite-exponent  ($n\gt 2$) counterexample with ordinary exponentiation? If so, please post, since it would also be interesting.

Comment: Thanks. Anyway, what I wanted to mention that ages ago, Ehrenfeucht and others studied the question when two structures given by ordinals are elementarily equivalent. I believe that for statements like here ($\forall_1$ sentences using $+$ and $\cdot$, whether usual or natural), it should imply that if there is a counterexample, there is also one with $x,y,z<\omega^{\omega^\omega}$ (or maybe $\omega^{\omega^{\omega^2}}$, or something like that).

Comment: Sounds great! Please post. I would hope for a counterexample with explicit ordinals, if they can be found so small.

Comment: In fact, now I think one can show there is no counterexample by a simple direct argument. I’ll post it shortly.

Comment: Great! Presumably your simple argument will appeal to Wiles's result? After all, proving there are no counterexamples here is at least as hard as the FLT itself.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There are no nontrivial solutions. This follows from Wiles’s proof, and the following observation.

**Proposition:** If a set of Diophantine equations has a solution in (positive) ordinals using natural sum and product, then it has a solution in (positive) natural numbers.

**Proof:** Every ordinal can be uniquely written in Cantor normal form
$$\tag{$*$}\alpha=\sum_{i<k}\omega^{\alpha_i}n_i,$$
where $\alpha_i>\alpha_{i+1}$ and $0<n_i<\omega$ for all $i<k$. Define a function $f\colon\mathrm{Ord}\to\omega$ by $f(\alpha)=\sum_jn_j$. Notice that $f(\alpha)=0$ only if $\alpha=0$, and $f(n)=n$ for all $n<\omega$. The proposition follows from

**Claim:** $f$ is a homomorphism with respect to natural sum and product.

This in turn follows from expression of the operations in terms of Cantor normal form. For sum, let $\alpha$ and
$$\beta=\sum_i\omega^{\alpha_i}m_i$$
be as in $(*)$, except that we allow $n_i$ and $m_i$ to be zero. Then their natural sum is
$$\def\ns{\mathbin\#}\alpha\ns\beta=\sum_i\omega^{\alpha_i}(n_i+m_i),$$
hence
$$f(\alpha\ns\beta)=\sum_i(n_i+m_i)=f(\alpha)+f(\beta).$$
As for product, the expression in $(*)$ is valid even if we interpret the sum and product there as the natural operations, and natural product is associative and distributive over natural sum, hence it suffices to consider only the case of $\alpha=\omega^{\alpha_0}$ and $\beta=\omega^{\beta_0}$. However, then their natural product is $\gamma=\omega^{\alpha_0\ns\beta_0}$, and $f(\gamma)=1=f(\alpha)f(\beta)$.

Comment: Fantastic! But could you explain a bit more why $\omega^{\alpha_0}\cdot\omega^{\beta_0}=\omega^{\alpha_0\#\beta_0}$ in the last paragraph? This was a question asked above in the comments by Garrett Ervin.

Comment: According to http://www.ohio.edu/people/ehrlich/AHES.pdf (p. 24), this is the *definition* of natural product. I can’t wrap my head around the definition on Wikipedia, but hopefully it resolves to the same thing.

Comment: This answer also has an application to the question at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/150804/the-theory-of-transfinite-diophantine-equations/150816#150816, if one should use natural arithmetic there.

Comment: By the way, since $(\mathrm{Ord},0,\ns)$ is a free commutative monoid generated by powers of $\omega$, it is not hard to describe all homomorphisms $F\colon(\mathrm{Ord},\ns,\times)\to(\omega,+,\cdot)$: apart from constant $0$, they are of the form $$F(\sum_i\omega^{\sum_j\omega^{\alpha_{i,j}}m_{i,j}}n_i)=\sum_in_i\prod_jH(\alpha_{i,j})^{m_{i,j}},$$ where $H\colon\mathrm{Ord}\to\omega$ is an arbitrary function. For example, by taking $H(\alpha)=c$ constant, one can ensure that $F(\alpha)\ge c$ for all infinite ordinals $\alpha$.

Comment: Might this answer change if we move the the Grothendieck ring of the ordinals under commutative operations? Your claim that $f(\alpha)=0\iff\alpha=0$ is no longer true, for example with $\omega-1$. I will ask this as a separate question.

Comment: I think the answer is the same. Basically, you just need to show that for a given nonzero element $a$ (namely, $xyz$ from a purported solution $x^n+y^n=z^n$), there exists a homomorphism from the ring to $\mathbb Z$ that maps $a$ to a nonzero number. Now, the Grothendieck ring is simply the ring of multivariate integer polynomials with the ordinals $\omega^{\omega^\alpha}$ playing the role of indeterminates; we get a homomorphism by evaluating all indeterminates with integers. Thus, it suffices to note that any nonzero multivariate polynomial attains a nonzero value on some integer inputs.

Comment: Oh, I didn’t notice that you reposted it as a question meanwhile.

Answer (score 7):

The review (by Erdos) of Sierpinski, Le dernier théorème de Fermat pour les nombres ordinaux, Fund. Math. 37 (1950) 201–205, MR0040372 (12,683c), says, "...there are arbitrarily large transfinite ordinals $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$, $\alpha\lt\beta\lt\gamma$ so that for all $n=1,2,\dots$, $\alpha^n+\beta^n=\gamma^n$. I haven't looked at the paper, so I don't know whether this is in natural or usual ordinal arithmetic.

Comment: I think it must be the usual ordinal arithmetic. In Sierpiński's *Cardinal and Ordinal Numbers*, in a remark on p. 321 following Exercise XIV.18.7 ("Prove that for transfinite ordinal numbers $\lambda$ of the second kind, we have $1^{\lambda}+2^{\lambda}=3^{\lambda}$"), he says "For Fermat's last theorem on transfinite exponents see [that 1950 paper]". Natural sums and products are introduced later in the book, on p. 366.

Comment: Article: http://pldml.icm.edu.pl:80/pldml/element/bwmeta1.element.bwnjournal-article-fmv37i1p16

Comment: Thanks, @François! The article is in French, but it is clear that he is using the (usual) non-commutative arithmetic. What isn't clear to me yet is whether his example still works also in the natural arithmetic.